# Showing images on same axes

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a basic question about MATLAB. How I can show two images on same axes? I don't want it to be in same figure (as the following code shows) but the same axes.

```
subplot(1,2,1), subimage(X)
subplot(1,2,2), subimage(X2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need [`hold on`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hold.html) to plot two graphs on the same axes:

```
figure
subimage(X)
hold on
subimage(X2)
```

Comment: Thanks ... I know hold on command. What I am looking for is that I have a structural image from brain and an activation image from brain. I need to draw both images in same axes to show the activated brain. hold on does not help here.

Comment: Do you want to overlay both images? For example, red channel for structural image and green channel for activation?

Comment: Can you also add that information to your original question?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display two images side-by-side in the same `axes` you'll want to modify the [`XData`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/the-image-object-and-its-properties.html#f2-14273) property of the second image to shift it to the right of the first image

```
X = rand(10);
X2 = rand(10);

figure
subimage(X)
hold on
him2 = subimage(X2);
set(him2, 'XData', get(him2, 'XData') + size(X, 2))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response... I think I have not asked my question thoroughly. What I am looking for is that I have a structural image from brain and an activation image from brain. I need to draw both images in same axes to show the activated brain.

Comment: @Shnu66 So how exactly do you plan to see both images if they are on top of one another?